# Can gtags navigate back?

Tags: vim, gnu-global

I use vim with gtags plug in to read code through multiple files. Everything is okay except that I donnot know how to navigate back to the previous position before I run :CtagsCursor to jump to the token definition. I read through the GNU global online docs, but find nothing useful. But in the chapter "3.4 Elvis using GLOBAL", it says "CTRL-T return to the most recent tag context.", which is exactly what I wants. No idea why the function is not implemented for vim, or something is wrong with me?

BR, Ruochen

Comment: Hmm, `ctrl-t` should work. Try `ctrl-o` and see if it behaves like you want.

Answer (score 3):

`<C-t>` is a built-in command related to Vim's "tag stack".

It looks like the plugin you are using doesn't implement a similar feature (and doesn't interact with the tag stack anyway) so you are left with `<C-o>`/`<C-i>` to jump around the jump list.

Comment: If you want you can create a tags file via `global` e.g. `global -t . > ./tags`. This will allow you to use vim's ctag functionality however using "gtags" to build the database. You can also use set `'cscopeprg'` to `gtags-cscope` so you can get cscope functionality however I am not certain this allows the use of `<c-t>`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using `gtags-cscope` as `cscopeprog`. Additionally I activated cscopetag to use cscope for ctag lookup in vim, too. This way, if you press `<C-]>` you search for the declaration in gtags and `<C-t>` to go back again.

For lookups of references, which I mapped to `<C-\>`, I use the quickfix window. This does not use the tag stack and `<C-t>` will not work.

I tried it, using the tag stack, but this leads to a cluttered tag stack and a large selection window. If you lookup multiple references you have to press `<C-t>` multiple time, that's why I decided using the quickfix approach instead.

Here is my actual config.

```
set cscopeprg=gtags-cscope
if has('cscope')
  set cscopetag cscopeverbose
  if has('quickfix')
    set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
  endif

  map <C-\> :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
endif
```

If you like to give the reference lookup without quickfix a try, remove the `c-` option in `cscopequickfix`.

Another hint, `cscopeverbose` is a option to print error messages when using cscope. Otherwise you won't get errors (e.g. no gtags file added, or symbol not found).

**EDIT 1:**

To load a GTAGS file, use the built-in command `cs add ./GTAGS`.

Comment: This is nice. The only thing it's missing is loading the cscope database. It would be nice if we could use syntax like vim already supports with tags `set tags=./tags;`.

Comment: @seanahern Instead of setting `tags`, you can use the command `cs add ./GTAGS` to use a built-in command.

Comment: Um, right, but `cs add` doesn't search up the path hierarchy like vim has built in to its "set tags" command. What I'm talking about is the ability to search for a particular file (in this case `GTAGS`) in the current directory, then up each successive parent directory until the file is found.

Answer (score 1):

GNU GLOBAL has two handy vim plugins `gtags.vim` and `gtags-cscope.vim`.

The heading comment of `gtags-cscope.vim` says that it is used to integrate GLOBAL with Vim's `cscope` interface.

So what you have to do is:

1. Install the vim plugins (They are in the [tarball](https://www.gnu.org/software/global))

   - `cp /path/to/global-source/*.vim ~/plugin/`
2. Add some options in `~/.vimrc`

The heading comment of `gtags-cscope.vim` has all the available options.
In my case, I use the following:

```
" To use the default key/mouse mapping:
let GtagsCscope_Auto_Map = 1
" If you hope auto loading:
let GtagsCscope_Auto_Load = 1
" Don't show warning if GTAGS not found
let GtagsCscope_Quiet = 1
" To use 'vim -t ', ':tag' and '<C-]>'
set cscopetag
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through the docs and it seems tag stack isn't supported with gnu-global in vim according to section 3.5.1. Features:
http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Features_0028Vim_0029

In the above description, there is a link to setting up the plugin which uses tag stack, so check that out.

Other than that using `ctrl-o` and `ctrl-i` as substitutes should work fine.